# Design up (2 story) or out

Tags: new-home, architecture

I am not a builder. I am looking at properties with garage/shop + apartment.

The two designs pictured are equivalent. From what I have seen most properties take the build out (left) approach.

To me it seems more efficient to build the apartment up. Less slab and less roof. Took 2' off the apt on the out (left) design for not requiring stairs.  But also lose storage under the stairs.

Up (right) I understand there is cost to support the apartment.

**From a cost perspective which is a better design?**

Not sure it matters but cool climate - no A/C.

I am asking because I may purchase land and build.

The model is a 1-5 acre lot with the expectation the buyer would build a main home. I don't need much living space and I want a structure with lowest cost.

Going with $6 sq ft for slab and $7 sf roof is about $8000. Basically the apt gets a free roof and slab with with 2 story. Unless is cost more than $8000 to hang an apartment that should be cheaper.

[image]

Comment: Garages under living spaces are loud. Is the garage conditioned? If not, that's a lot of heat or cold to insulate your floor against. If your apartment is on the second floor, it involves stairs for everything that goes in or out of the apartment.

Comment: Garages also add some cost for the fire rating. My last home was 2 level but finally went to single level because of 17 knee surgery's so stairs can affect resale but most new tract homes are multi level because of the reduced footprint cost.

Comment: @Drew I think would would rather insulate a floor to still air than the ground.  I understand it involved stairs.  My question is cost.

Comment: @EdBeal The intended model here is a 1-5 acre lot expecting the next buyer to put in a full size home.  I will update the question.

Comment: Don’t call me to help carry those groceries upstairs every time you go shopping. My friends are too lazy to climb all those stairs to come visit.

Comment: @LeeSam Not the question.

Comment: @paparazzo It’s all about the cost...especially when you try to sell the monster.

Comment: @LeeSam Still not the stated question, thank you.

Comment: @paparazzo I disagree. You wanted to know which is better “from a cost perspective.”  Well, there’s: 1) initial cost, 2) maintenance cost, and 3) final (long term) cost. Don’t be so snarky and try understanding what people are trying to tell you. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, two story is probably less cost to build because it has a smaller “footprint”, but it’s less than you think: 1) The footings can be smaller because they are supporting one floor and not two, 2) Two story will require additional square footage for circulation (stairs), 3) Because of the height of your RV, you’ll have additional height requirement than normal which will require special scaffolding for construction, 4) Possible special water pump due to extra height of second floor, 5) Additional space required for “Entry” downstairs, and 6) Extra fire rated protection between garage space and living space above. (Fire material is required between garage and living for single story too, but easier to install and less required.)

Maintenance is more for two story: washing windows, paint, cleaning the gutters, etc.

The two story option gives you more privacy, but you’ll have the largest thighs in the county.

Comment: It seems like height of RV is the same factor on  both.  If anything it forces extra height on more sq ft on the out design.  I made the apt 2' less on the out design to account for stair case.  My city is full of 3 story condo and houses.

Comment: @paparazzo You’re right, you’re not a builder. You don’t understand that the height of a structure is not proportional to its height. When you build a second floor, it’s more expensive than building two one stories. Then, put that second floor on an extra high (tall) first floor and the cost is extra expensive. Also, if you live in a high wind or seismic area, you’ll pay extra for lack of shear walls on the garage door side of the building. The only way to know the difference in costs is to get a bid from a licensed builder.

Comment: You know for a fact two one story are cheaper than one two story?  I am not a builder  but am having trouble  believing that.  I know a slab and roofing is expensive.  Thank you for your input.

Comment: @paparazzo I’m pretty sure building 16’ in the air is more expensive than building at ground level.